# Is there any way to find views on android device using uiautomator api instead of using uiautomatorviewer manually?

Tags: android, ui-testing

can i write a code using uiautomator api to find all the views on device and their details  instead of using uiautomatorviewer and taking a snapshot to find all the details?

Answer (score 0):

Using **Robotium** you can get all the views on the device and their details.
It provides `solo.getCurrentViews ()` which will return an ArrayList of the View objects currently shown in the focused Activity or Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

[UiObject](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiObject.html) represents a view. Here is an official [example on how to obtain it](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html#classes).